# Getting a zend application on dev

Tags: zend-framework, config, propel

There's a web application developped with zend+propel and hosted on a production server (a debian squeeze). I need to replicate this application on my local pc (wich is a windows 7 + wamp).

I added a virtual host in httpd.conf:

```
<VirtualHost *:8083>
  DocumentRoot "c:/wamp/www/myapp/public"
  <Directory "c:/wamp/www/myapp/public">
      Options All
      AllowOverride All
      Allow from all
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

When I open the dev application on my browser I get this result:

```
doctype() ?> headTitle(); ?> headMeta(); ?> headStyle(); ?> headLink(); ?> headScript(); ?>
render('menu.phtml') ?>
render('session.phtml') ?>
```

I use xdebug to try to find the issue. But when I set a breakpoint in the indexAction of the IndexController, it is not hit by the debugger.

I created a sample zend application on the side and I could get to make it works. Now I don't have any clue about what's going on...

Is there a zend guru to save me ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to enable `short_open_tag` in your PHP configuration. See http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.short-open-tag

This config option allows `<?=` to work as a shorthand to `<?php echo`, e.g. `<?=$this->headTitle()?>`. At the moment these statements in your templates are being rendered as text.